# ReactJS: Other users accessing the website do not see the updated component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm trying to develop this website using Spotify Web API. The purpose of the website is for me and my friends to suggest songs and add them to a queue and we can vote on them. The functionality works perfectly fine with just me using it: adding songs, upvotes and downvotes. However, when my friend opens the website (using the same link that I use), his website's component is only rendered to the initial state but not the updated state that I see.

What I see:
[image]

What my friend sees using the same link at that moment:
[image]

My code structure is like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...

    this.state = {
      ...
      queue: [],
      vote: [],
    }

    this.addToQueue = this.addToQueue.bind(this);
    this.removeFromQueue = this.removeFromQueue.bind(this);
    this.onVoteUp = this.onVoteUp.bind(this);
    this.onVoteDown = this.onVoteDown.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     ...
  }

  addToQueue(song) {
    var newQueue = this.state.queue.slice();
    var newVote = this.state.vote.slice();
    if (!newQueue.includes(song)) {
      newQueue.push(song);
      newVote.push(0);
      this.setState({
        queue: newQueue,
        vote: newVote,
      });
    }
  }

  onVoteUp(index) {
    ...
  }

  onVoteDown(index) {
     ...
  }

  removeFromQueue() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div id="after-log-in">
          ... 
          <Queue
            queue={this.state.queue}
            vote={this.state.vote}
            addToQueue={this.addToQueue}
            onVoteUp={this.onVoteUp}
            onVoteDown={this.onVoteDown}>
          </Queue>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

and then I also have a Queue component to serve its functionality. I think the problem lies in the fact that my friend's website state is initialized to `queue: []`. I tried to use localStorage but when he opens the website his localStorage is also different from mine. Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

p/s: sorry for the unfriendly UI I haven't really tried to make it visually appealing until its functionality works.

Comment: as you correctly identified, the upvotes/downvotes are stored locally, either in the memory managed by your browser or in local storage.  Locally in this case means on the computer of whoever is viewing the page.  If you want data to be the same for you and your friend, you'll need to store the data on a server (a different computer), which the client (your computer) will probably make http calls with to store/update/read the data.

Comment: You need to setup a persistent storage source such as a database and an api to access that storage source through http protocols